# Is there a way discord.py can listen for multiple commands at once?

Tags: python, api, discord.py

I'm a little bit new to discord.py API and I have a command that takes like 4 minutes to execute and I can't seem to figure out how to get the bot to still listen to commands while that command is processing. If anyone has any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: Please, provide a code of your command.

Comment: I think that you need to make your command asyncronous.

Answer (score 0):

The bot should still be working since discord.py uses asynchronous functions

Answer (score 0):

First off, discord.py is NOT an API. It's a wrapper written in python for discord API. [More about API wrappers](https://rapidapi.com/blog/api-glossary/api-wrapper/#:%7E:text=In%20that%20line%2C%20an%20API,complicated%20functions%20easy%20to%20use.&text=Instead%20of%20calling%20an%20API,calls%20into%20a%20single%20task.)

Chances are, you are running [a blocking code](https://mobiforge.com/design-development/the-guide-to-non-blocking-code.)
Running stuff in an async function does not make it 'non-blocking'
(I am totally aware that the link is for a web page that talks about JavaScript but the idea of blocking is the same)

If you are carrying out heavy tasks such as image rendering or other stuff, you might want to run it with [loop.run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor)

```py
from discord.ext import commands

def heavy_task(arg1, arg2):
    # your blocking code here, not asynchronous or coro calls here
    return # return from this function


@bot.command()
async def test(ctx: commands.Context, ...)
    loop = bot.loop
    arg1 = # some value function needs
    arg2 = # some other value function needs
    return_variable = await loop.run_in_executor(None, heavy_task, arg1, arg2)
    # do the rest of the stuff with return_variable, sending or whatever
```